# Communication between Angular directives and their parent controller

Tags: design-patterns, angularjs

I'm trying to provide a convention, or standard, for a parent controller to communicate with a directive in Angular.

Basically the directive will have a "settings" object containing callbacks and initial data received from the controller, and an "api" object containing public functions.

I've created a service called "gabby" but it doesn't do much, just a convenience.

#### HTML

```
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <my-dir settings="myDirSettings" api="myDirApi"></my-dir>
  </div>
```

#### Parent Controller

```
  angular.module('myApp').controller('appCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myDirSettings = {
      onStart: function() {
        //start the logic
      },
      defaultName: 'My App Name'
    };

    $scope.someClick = function() {
      $scope.myDirApi.fetchData();
    };        
  });
```

#### Directive

Just Angular

```
  angular.module('myApp').directive('myDir', function() {
    return {
      controller: 'myDirCtrl',
      scope: { settings: '<', api: '=' }
    };
  });
```

Or with the Gabby Service

```
  angular.module('myApp').directive('myDir', function(gabby) {
    return {
      controller: 'myDirCtrl',
      scope: gabby.scope()
    };
  });
```

#### Directive's Controller

Just Angular

```
  angular.module('myApp').controller('myDirCtrl', function($scope) {
      angular.extend($scope, {
          onStart: function() {},
          onSubmit: function() {},
          defaultName: 'John'  
        }, $scope.settings);
      $scope.api = $scope.api || {};
      $scope.api.clearValues = function() {
          //do magic things
      };
      $scope.api.fetchData = function() {
          //do magic things
      };
      $scope.api.getValues = function() {
          //do magic things
      };        

      $scope.onSomeKeyPress = function() {        
        $scope.onStart();
      };
});
```

Or with the Gabby Service

```
  angular.module('myApp').controller('myDirCtrl', function($scope, gabby) {
    gabby.for($scope)
      .settings({
          //These are the default settings for the directive,
          //allowing the reader to easily understand what can
          //be passed to the directive
          onStart: function() {},
          onSubmit: function() {},
          defaultName: 'John'  
        })
      .api({
          //These are the public functions of the directives
          clearValues: function() {
            //do magic things
          },
          fetchData: function() {
            //do magic things
          },
          getValues: function() {
            //do magic things
          }
      });

    $scope.onSomeKeyPress = function() {        
      $scope.onStart();
    };
  });
```

More details:
https://github.com/yellowblood/gabby

- Am I trying to solve an already solved problem?
- Do you think this approach is readable and clear?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you'd use a service as an intermediary between the directive and the component.
Change the state of a service in a directive and then the controller can look at the data in the service for whatever it's interested in.